# Close accordian item when another is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, toggle

Here is a working sample on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mLugf6fk/)

Im trying to add a snippet to close the open accordians items when one is clicked. I have added a class "open" but cant seem to remove the class when another is clicked on.

Currently they can all be open but I would like ot prevent this from happening as it takes up too much space on mobile devices and forces the background to scroll which also causes the nav to collapse.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {


    // header js
        (function($) {
        $.fn.menumaker = function(options) {  
         var cssmenu = $(this), settings = $.extend({
           format: "dropdown",
         }, options);
         return this.each(function() {
           $(this).find(".hamburger-button").on('click', function(){
             $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
             var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
             if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) { 
               mainmenu.slideToggle().removeClass('open');
             }
             else {
               mainmenu.slideToggle().addClass('open');
               if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
                 mainmenu.find('ul').show();
               }
             }
           });
           cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');
           
           

          

          $('#cssmenu li.active').addClass('open').children('ul').show();
            $('#cssmenu li.has-sub>a').on('click', function(){
              $(this).removeAttr('href');
              var element = $(this).parent('li');
              if (element.hasClass('open')) {
                element.removeClass('open');
                element.find('li').removeClass('open');
                element.find('ul').slideUp(200);
              }
              else {
                element.addClass('open');
                element.children('ul').slideDown(200);
                element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp(200);
                element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
                element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
                element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp(200);
              }
            });

        

      /*
           
          multiTg = function() {
             cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
             cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
               $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
               if ($(this).siblings('.has-sub').hasClass('open')) {
                 $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').slideToggle();
               }
               else {
                 $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').slideToggle();
               }
             });
           };
      */     
      
     
           if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
           else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');
           
           
           
        resizeFix = function() {
          var mediasize = 1000;
             if ($( window ).width() > mediasize) {
               cssmenu.find('ul').show();
             }
             if ($(window).width() <= mediasize) {
               cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
             }
           };
           resizeFix();
           return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);
         });
          };
        })($);

        (function($){
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#cssmenu").menumaker({
           format: "multitoggle"
        });
        });
        })($);


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
      cssmenu.children().forEach(function(elem){
         if(elem === mainmenu){
           continue;
         }
         elem.removeClass('open');
      });
      mainmenu.slideToggle().addClass('open');
      if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
        mainmenu.find('ul').show();
      }
```

before adding the open class, clear it from all other elements.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. It looks like by clearing from all of the other elements prior, it prevents the accordion from opening altogether. https://jsfiddle.net/mLugf6fk/3/

Comment: I've made an update: https://jsfiddle.net/mLugf6fk/22/ and can now get the accordian items to open/close as they should but now ive lost the +/- indicators (code is commented out in example)